# How do I distinguish between generic Observable types in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, typescript2.0

I am trying to follow this [example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) in learning `switchMap` for `rxjs`. The running example is [here](http://jsbin.com/zahohikaha/1/edit?html,js,console,output) and written in TypeScript. I attempted to code something similar in TypeScript (Angular 2) in VS Code, but I get a compiler error.

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 
'Observable | Observable' and 
'Observable | Observable'.
(parameter) curr: Observable | Observable
```

My code is as follows.

```
playSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
pauseSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
interval$  = Observable.interval(1000).mapTo(-1);
pause$ = Observable.from(this.pauseSubject).mapTo(Observable.of(false));
resume$ = Observable.from(this.playSubject).mapTo(this.interval$);
timer$ = Observable
  .merge(this.pause$, this.resume$)
  .startWith(this.interval$)
  .switchMap(v => Observable.of(v))
  .scan((acc, curr) => {
    return curr ? curr + acc : acc; //problem right here
  });
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.timer$.subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
play() { //bound to button click event
  this.playSubject.next(true);
}
pause() { //bound to button click event
  this.pauseSubject.next(false);
}
```

I can modify the code in the `scan` function as follows, but then I'd need to know whether `curr` was `Observable<boolean>` or `Observable<number>`.

```
playSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
pauseSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
interval$  = Observable.interval(1000).mapTo(-1);
pause$ = Observable.from(this.pauseSubject).mapTo(Observable.of(false));
resume$ = Observable.from(this.playSubject).mapTo(this.interval$);
timer$ = Observable
  .merge(this.pause$, this.resume$)
  .startWith(this.interval$)
  .switchMap(v => Observable.of(v))
  .scan((acc, curr) => {
    return curr; //how do i check for Observable<Type>?
  });
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong or how to check for the Observable type inside `scan`?

Comment: What's the reason behind the votes to close?

Comment: Why are you using `Observable.of` in the `switchMap`? The example you provided doesn't.

Comment: I get a compile error in VS Code if I don't do that. Note the example is in TypeScript, but a copy/paste job of that into VS Code (inside an Angular 2 project) doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't the problem in `.startWith(this.interval$)` where you start the sequence with an Observable? Operator `startWith` just reemits the Observable as is without subscribing to it http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/startWith.js.html#lineNumber19

Comment: How is that a problem? I took this code almost verbatim from learnrxjs.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to properly fix this in VS Code you need to provide the following aid to the transpiler with generic type parameters:

```
timer$ = Observable
  .merge(this.pause$, this.resume$)
  .startWith(this.interval$)
  .switchMap<Observable<boolean> | Observable<number>, boolean | number>(v => v)
  .scan<boolean | number, number>((acc, curr) => {
    return curr && typeof curr === "number" ? curr + acc : acc;
  }, 60);
```

So this tells the transpiler that the input to the `switchMap` is an `Observable<boolean>` or an `Observable<number>` and its output is either a `boolean` or `number`.

Then we tell the `scan` method that its input is either a `boolean` or a `number` and its seed value's type is a `number`.

We are not stopping here, because this would still confuse the transpiler when it encounters the `curr + acc` expression. This is because `curr`'s type is `boolean | number` and `acc`'s type is `number`.

For this I introduced an additional condition in the ternary operator: `typeof curr === "number"` which makes the transpiler happy and the code will transpile. This is working because of a feature called: [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Also note that the `Observable.of` is not necessary in the `switchMap`.